# Para que sirve process="@this" e immediate="true" en Primefaces

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Llevo un tiempo trabajando con ***Primefaces y JSF*** y la verdad es que aun me es dificil comprender para que sirve exactamente los atributos:

```
process="@this"
immediate="true"
```

A veces cuando *alguna accion* no actualiza mis elementos, agrego estas líneas y hace que funcione bien lo que necesito, pero sigo sin entender:

**¿Qué hacen exactamente?**

**¿Cual es la diferencia entre un process y un update?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo leer la documentación relacionada al ciclo de vida de JSF, para que comprendas todo el proceso del request y response que ocurre. Para esto te invito a que leas este link

[Ciclo de vida de JSF](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaqq.html)

También te recomiendo descargar la guía de usuario de primefaces desde:

[Guía de usuario de primefaces 6.2](https://www.primefaces.org/documentation/)

Ahí específicamente a la sección 4.2 Partial Processing y lee con atención lo que ahí encontrarás.

No término sin antes explicarte con mis palabras para que sirven *process="@this" e
immediate="true"*.

Algunos componentes de primefaces tienen esas propiedades y específicamente aquellos que pueden hacer la tarea de poder hacer un POST -enviar datos al servidor- a través de HTTP. Generalmente esto se hace a través de un formulario -form-, entonces:

**process="@this"** indica que el componente que lo tiene será el único objeto -dato- que será enviado al servidor, excluyendo a cualquier otro que existe en el formulario. Lo contrario a este sería process="@all" o bien process="@form" ambos enviaran todos los objetos de datos al servidor. El proceso se detendrá si un dato no es valido.

Ahora **immediate="true"** ayuda a omitir el proceso de validación de tal forma que si tuvieras un botón dentro de un formulario y tuviera process="@form" e immediate="true" todos los datos serian enviados pese a que alguno fuera "requerido". Hay que tener cuidado con esta combinación.

Pero te invito a leer los documentos que te anexo a través de links.

Answer (score 6):

El atributo @Process se ejecuta del lado del servidor y solo puede afectar a los UIComponents que implementan EditableValueHolder (campos de entrada) o ActionSource (campos de comando). El atributo Process le indica a Primefaces, qué componentes se deben procesar en ese momento.

En pocas palabras, le estas diciendo a Primefaces que envie y/o procese del lado del servidor los UIComponents indicados. En el caso de @this, le estas diciendo que procese el componente que tiene el atributo, si es un boton le estas indicado que procese el boton, es decir, que lo ejecute, y esto se realiza del lado del servidor.

El atributo immediate="true" le indica a PrimeFaces que no tome en cuenta las validaciones que estas realizando sobre el UIComponent que tiene el atributo. Si tienes por ejemplo una validacion de longitud de un campo de texto, con este atributo no se tomara en cuenta.

Una descripcion mas larga y completa sobre process lo puedes conseguir aqui:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes